# Test class - code coverage help

Tags: apex, trigger, code-coverage

I need help on test class, this is my class:

When creating a task of type (Phone Call or Last Face to Face) then update the account fields

I have a trigger:

```
trigger TaskTrigger on Task (after delete, after insert, after undelete, after update, before delete, before insert, before update) {

    TaskTriggerHandler handler = new TaskTriggerHandler (Trigger.isExecuting, Trigger.size);
    //After Update
     if(Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isAfter){
         handler.OnAfterUpdate(Trigger.new,Trigger.oldMap);

   }
 }
```

TriggerHandler class:

```
public with sharing class TaskTriggerHandler {

    private boolean trigger_isExecuting = false;
    private integer batchSize = 0;

    public TaskTriggerHandler ( boolean isExecuting, integer size){
        trigger_isExecuting = isExecuting;
        batchSize = size;        
    }

    public void OnAfterUpdate(List<Task> Tklist, Map<id,Task> OldMaplst){
        //EXECUTE AFTER UPDATE LOGIC
        //first condition is to check the record type then 
         Set<ID> tid = new Set<ID>();
         list<Account> acclst = new list<Account>();

        for(Task tk:Tklist){
        if(tk.Whoid!=null && tk.WhoId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName()=='Contact'){
         tid.add(tk.whoid);
            }
          }
        List<Contact> con = new List<Contact>();
        con=[select id,accountid from Contact where id =:tid];
        Map<id,account>Lstacc=new Map<id,account>();
        if(!con.isEmpty()){
            account acc;
            for(Task tk:[select id,LastModifiedBy.name,type,LastModifiedDate from task where id in :Tklist]){
                DateTime dt = tk.LastModifiedDate;
                Date myDate = date.newinstance(dt.year(), dt.month(), dt.day());
                acc=new account(id=con[0].accountid);
                    if(tk.type=='Face 2 Face Meeting'){
                        acc.Last_Face_to_Face_Activity__c= myDate;
                        acc.Last_Visited_By__c =tk.LastModifiedBy.name;

                    }
                    else if(tk.type=='Phone Call'){
                     acc.Last_Call_Activity__c =  myDate;
                    }
                     Lstacc.put(acc.id,acc);
        }
                if(!Lstacc.isEmpty())
                    Update Lstacc.values();

    }
  }
}
```

My test class:

```
@isTest
public class TaskTriggerHandler_Task {

    static testmethod void TestTriggerHandler(){
        // find insurance agent record type
     // RecordType acctInsAgent = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType ='Account' AND DeveloperName ='Insurance_Agent'];


       Account a = new Account (Name='Insurance Agent Test');
        insert a;

        //Create a contact 
        Contact c = new Contact(FirstName = 'fname', LastName = 'lname',Email = 'test@gmail.com', Phone = '1234567890');
        insert c; 

        test.startTest();

        //Create a Task 
        task t = new Task(Subject='Donni',
        Priority='Normal',
        type='Phone Call', 
        status ='Completed',
        WhoId = c.Id,
        WhatId = a.Id                
        );

        insert t;

        if(t.Type == 'Phone Call'){

           //update account with last face to face, last call activity and last touched by fields
               DateTime dt = t.LastModifiedDate;
                Date myDate = date.newinstance(dt.year(), dt.month(), dt.day());
               a.Last_Face_to_Face_Activity__c = myDate;

            update a;

            system.assertEquals(myDate, a.Last_Face_to_Face_Activity__c);
           test.stopTest();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The specific problem here is that your test class doesn't invoke your trigger by performing an update operation, instead doing the trigger's work within the test class. Please read the linked duplicate questions and their resources to learn more about how to write an effective test class.

Comment: Thanks for the comment David. I' ll update my test class and thanks all for the helpful resources.